# Connected components std::pair<std::int, std::int> how to

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, adjacency-list

I have a pair representation `std::pair<std::int,std::int>` of an adjacency list like so:

```
(0,0)
(0,3)
(1,0)
(1,1)
(2,3)
(3,0)
(3,1)
(3,2)
(3,3)
```

(so node 0 is connected to nodes 0 and 3, node 1 is connected to nodes 0 and 1, and so forth).

What is the smartest way to find connected components with this representation?

I'm *not* supposed to change the input, so converting it to a matrix (for example) and running DFS on it is *not* an option.

How do I best approach this?

Comment: What does "find connected components" mean? What is the input to your function, and what are you expected to return?

Comment: The first entry of node 0 of a pair is different from the node 0 of the second entry of the same pair? Otherwise node 0 is connected to itself?

Comment: Yes, nodes can be connected to themselves.
If you use an adjacency matrix representation, the above would look like so:


`{1,0,0,1}`
`{1,1,0,0}` 
`{0,0,0,1}`  
`{1,1,1,1}`

Here, we can see three groups of '1s' (where the top right is a component on its own), so we have 3 connected components.

(Looks like line breaks are not allowed in comments, so imagine the four lines underneath each other (rather than side by side)).

Comment: You can use a [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Add all the edges and query each node to find which component it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all (particularly [BessieTheCow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9254539/bessiethecow) for pointing out the disjoint-set data structure).

In the end, it turned out to be just an ordinary DFS:

`typedef std::unordered_set<std::pair<int,int>, Pairhash> adjacencySet;`

```
//Needed for unordered_set
struct Pairhash {
public:
  template <typename T, typename U>
  std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T, U> &x) const
  {
    return std::hash<T>()(x.first) ^ std::hash<U>()(x.second);
  }
};
```

```
void dfs(std::shared_ptr<adjacencySet> visited, const std::pair<int, int> &pair, const adjacencySet &adjacencies)
{
    if (visited->find(pair) != visited->end())
    {
        return;
    }
    visited->emplace(pair);
    std::pair<int,int> temp;
    if (pair.first > 0)
    {
        temp = std::make_pair(pair.first -1, pair.second); //Look up
        if (adjacencies.find(temp) != adjacencies.end())
        {
            dfs(visited, temp, adjacencies);
        }
    }
    if (pair.second > 0)
    {
        temp = std::make_pair(pair.first, pair.second-1); //Look left
        if (adjacencies.find(temp) != adjacencies.end())
        {
            dfs(visited, temp, adjacencies);
        }
    }
    temp = std::make_pair(pair.first +1, pair.second); //Look down
    if (adjacencies.find(temp) != adjacencies.end())
    {
        dfs(visited, temp, adjacencies);
    }
    temp = std::make_pair(pair.first, pair.second +1); //Look right
    if (adjacencies.find(temp) != adjacencies.end())
    {
        dfs(visited, temp, adjacencies);
    }
}
```

```
int countComponents(const adjacencySet &adjacencies)
{
    std::shared_ptr<adjacencySet> visited = std::make_shared<adjacencySet>(adjacencies.size());
    auto count(0);
    for (auto pair : adjacencies)
    {
        if (visited->find(pair) == visited->end())
        {
            dfs(visited, pair, adjacencies);
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

With an example set like so:

```
(0,0)   
(0,3)   
(1,0)    
(1,1)   
(2,3)   
(3,0)   
(3,1)   
(3,2)   
(3,3)
```

(this would be represented as

```
{1,0,0,1}   
{1,1,0,0}   
{0,0,0,1}   
{1,1,1,1}
```

in a matrix representation).